# Download every n-th pixel on every n-th frame of MP4 file

Tags: video, download, video-conversion

I work in an environment with limited bandwidth. I want to be able to download MP4 files but I don't care much about the quality. What I thought about to theoretically bring down the bandwidth usage to about one eighth would be to only download every fourth pixel and only every second frame.

Let me illustrate what I mean. `x` means "skipped".

So let's say we have an MP4 file that has a dimension of 8x4 so a frame looks this:

```
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
```

I'd like to to save bandwidth by only downloading the information needed like this:

```
OxOxOxOx
xxxxxxxx
OxOxOxOx
xxxxxxxx
```

So basically every 2x2 pixel block goes from

```
OO
OO
```

to

```
Ox
xx
```

So it's only one pixel downloaded instead of all four.

I would like to apply the same to frames. If an 8 fps video has a second looking like this

```
[ O O O O O O O O ]
```

it shall become this

```
[ O x O x O x O x ]
```

so only frames numbered `2*n` get downloaded.

I suppose that would more or less easily be possible with uncompressed files such as plain text documents or BMP images where the data of frame n does not depend on frame n-1 but I would like to know whether any of you can estimate how possible this is with MP4. The coded (?) in question is `isomiso2avc1mp41`

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know whether any of you can estimate how possible this
>   is with MP4

It is 0% possible

well technically it depends on what video codec is inside the mp4, but assuming its now raw (which would make the file absolutely huge) its probably using a codec that uses both temporal and and spacial compression. In their case its avc1, also called h264

Spacial compress in codecs is  performed by converting from the spacial domain to a frequency domain via a transform like the DTC. To recover a pixel you must have all the coefficients for the IDCT, That means downloading everything.

As far as skipping frames, You could skip any P (and maybe B) frames and only download key (IDR) frames. But key frames are spaced about 1 to 10 second apart on average. So if 0.1 fps is ok, the would cut the bandwidth by probably a little less than half.